# Python PLY - Skip Production Rule

Tags: python, yacc, ply

When using PLY, is it possible to skip a give production rule?
( In the same way that lex allows skipping certain tokens using obj.lexer.skip(1) )

For example:

```
def p_variable(p):
    'variable : identifier'
    if variabledict.getitem(p[1]) == None:
        p.parser.skip(1)  # <<
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not clear what (syntactically) is trying to be achieved and if it makes any sense at all. Is the code intended to only match identifiers that are already in the symbol table or declared in some way. Do you want a syntax error when undeclared identifiers are used, or is there some other goal?